# Do Windows 10 Mobile users have an Anniversary update like desktop users of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update

Do we have an Anniversary update to Windows 10 Mobile like desktop users of Windows 10? Will we see any noticeable features in this update?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, Windows 10 Mobile is receiving an anniversary update too. According to [this article](http://www.nokiapoweruser.com/windows-10-mobile-anniversary-update-review-video-walk-through-of-all-new-features-changes/):

> Microsoft will release the latest Windows 10 Mobile OS update known
>   officially as Windows 10 Mobile Anniversary update starting August 2
>   for supported devices.

The supported devices stated in the article quoted above are essentially those which are running Windows 10 Mobile (Build 10586.XXX) officially.

Notable improvements include:

- Faster and more responsive than Threshold
- Many usability improvements that really help
- Customization of Quick action buttons & notifications enhancements
- Better Control on notifications
- Battery Saver has become much easier to use and more powerful
- Cortana gets many exciting features including notification mirroring
- Microsoft Edge adds Swipe navigation, better tab behavior & UI
  changes
- Major apps revamps like Store, Skype, Maps, Groove Music, Mail &
  Calendar and more
- Good to Excellent Battery Life

You can also check [this article](http://www.nokiapoweruser.com/windows-10-mobile-anniversary-update-coming-this-summer-insiders-may-get-it-soon/) to see a list with more features coming in the anniversary update.